Give an user the permission to open an ssh tunnel with a specific port < 1024 (privileged port)
If you try to open a tunnel with a normal user with a port < 1024 with for example:
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:1023:someip:someport user@host -N

you can't because you get
bind [127.0.0.1]:1023: Permission denied

Given a specific port (< 1024) that the tunnel will use for binding, can I give a permission to a normal user to create a tunnel ?
Thanks for the help.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/413807/is-there-a-way-for-non-root-processes-to-bind-to-privileged-ports-on-linux

I tried authbind with no luck: I have created /etc/authbind/byport/1023  chown it for my user and chmod it 500, but no luck still permission denied
